# Using the LIKE condition in SELECT in BIG QUERY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to write a query with the LIKE condition (I can't use regex) but in one line. I have two conditions, for example:

```
select name 
from table1
where name like 'ANG% 
   or name like 'GA%'
```

but I can't write it in two separate `LIKE`.

Does anyone know how to write these two LIKE conditions in BIGQUERY, using e.g. square brackets:

```
LIKE '[AB]%'
```

Or is there another way to write it?

Comment: Look at [Quantified `LIKE` operator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#like_operator_quantified) (for example, `name LIKE ANY ('ANG%', 'GA%')`).

Comment: Thanks. The thing is that LIKE is entered in the code and I need to adjust the expression I enter after LIKE so that LIKE takes into account all conditions.
If bigquery doesn't support the query type I wrote above, then OK, maybe I should add ANY in my procedure.

Comment: Just for my curiosity, why can't you use regex?

Comment: Because LIKE is used in the procedure to connect to a large dictionary. Then someone used like and the dictionary is matched by LIKE. I can use regex, but I would have to change the dictionary and the connecting logic, it would definitely be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

The [Google BigQuery documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#like_operator) provides a solution for such cases : using an unnested array of patterns.

```
SELECT name
FROM table1 WHERE
  EXISTS(
    SELECT name FROM UNNEST(['ANG%', 'GA%']) AS pattern
    WHERE name LIKE pattern
  );
```